# Sharing an connection from guest to host vmware

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vpn, vmware, connection-sharing

My setup is like this:
Guest: Win 10
Host: Win 11

The guest has a vpn software installed in it, when the vpn is connected (it creates its own connection which is visible in Network Connections), the internet on guest stops working. The VPN lets us access this subnet `10.0.0.0/8` from the guest machine.

Is it possible to share that vpn connection from guest to host machine. So my host machine can access these VPN subnets while using internet as well.

Something like when the traffic is intended for `10.0.0.0/8`
I can add route like this `route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 (to that shared adapter or its IP)`

Can any one assist me

Comment: Can you enable split tunneling in the guest VPN?

Comment: Nope. This is not an option

Comment: Then you likely cannot do what you are trying to do. The connection is not properly made.